# How to download large files using objective c on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

I ve written an app that downloads files from a sever via http. The users will always be on WLAN when using my app. It downloads files of <10MB without any issues but the application just hangs for larger files.
Is there a best practice way to download large files or do i need to implement some form of chunking?

Any code samples would be much appreciated.
Many thanks
Tony

Comment: You should be careful, your app may be rejected in the end. You are not supposed to consume that much data across the WAN.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [`ASIHTTPRequest` library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest).

It can download files on the background without blocking your app, and can even hook into into a progress bar or something like that.  The ["How to use it"](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) provides lots of examples and sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Second on the ASIHTTPRequest library, it really is very good.  In addition, try downloading a much smaller part of the file(s) for a given request (I'm assuming they are XML or JSON files).  Only get more data if the user is requesting it (eg, user is scrolling past a certain point in a tableview).  Something to consider anyway.